# Summing from 2 Tables in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I need to write a SQL query that will sum a field (BranchRevenue) from two different tables (Insurance and Investments) into one number based on the grouping of a common field in each table (BrokerName).  The database is MS Access (I've provided a sample structure in the hyperlink below).

[image]

My understanding from looking at similar posts on SO is that I need to define the sums from the individual tables (which I can do) and then aggregate them together using DISTINCT or DISTINCTROW (which I cannot do).

Here are the individual queries for each table on their own which correctly sum BranchRevenue by BrokerName.

```
SELECT  Investments.BrokerName AS [BrokerName],Sum(Investments.BranchRevenue) as [BranchRevenue] 
FROM  Investments WHERE ( ((Investments.Ledger = 'Actual') AND (Investments.Year1 = 2017) AND (Investments.Period = 6) AND (Investments.Branch = 'Toronto') ) ) 
GROUP BY  Investments.BrokerName

SELECT  Insurance.BrokerName AS [BrokerName],Sum(Insurance.BranchRevenue) as [BranchRevenue] 
FROM  Insurance WHERE ( ((Insurance.Ledger = 'Actual') AND (Insurance.Year1 = 2017) 
    AND (Insurance.Period = 6) AND (Insurance.Branch = 'Toronto') ) ) 
GROUP BY  Insurance.BrokerName
```

How can I use a single SQL statement to accomplish this?

The ideal solution would correctly sum BranchRevenue from both tables as one number for each BrokerName while not duplicating data from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `union all` to combine the results from both tables before summing:

```
SELECT   [BrokerName], SUM([BranchRevenue])
FROM     (SELECT Investments.BrokerName AS [BrokerName],
                 Investments.BranchRevenue AS [BranchRevenue] 
          FROM   Investments 
          WHERE  Investments.Ledger = 'Actual' AND 
                 Investments.Year1 = 2017 AND 
                 Investments.Period = 6 AND 
                 Investments.Branch = 'Toronto'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT Insurance.BrokerName AS [BrokerName],
                 Insurance.BranchRevenue AS [BranchRevenue]
          FROM   Insurance
          WHERE  Insurance.Ledger = 'Actual' AND
                 Insurance.Year1 = 2017 AND
                 Insurance.Period = 6 AND
                 Insurance.Branch = 'Toronto'
         ) t
GROUP BY [BrokerName]
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your quick help.   =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple union all query and then group

```
select BrokerName, sum(BranchRevenue) from (
select * from Insurer
  where...
union all
select * from Investments
  where ...)
group by BrokerName
```